# Could not import idaapi. Name error: name 'idaapi' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, reverse-engineering, offset, ida

I have a python script that auto read and export particular offsets from a game. It's made with the help of IDA 6.6 and it's python scripts/libs. Now I am not very experienced with python and I don't know why I get this errors:

1. Could not import idaapi. Running in 'pydoc mode'.
2. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\1234\Desktop\idapyhon\offsets.py", line 1, in  from idc import BADADDR, INF_BASEADDR,  SEARCH_DOWN, FUNCATTR_START, FUNCATTR_END File "D:\prg\IDA 6.6\python\idc.py", line 41, in  **EA64** = idaapi.BADADDR == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL NameError: name 'idaapi' is not defined

offsets.py:
    pastebin.com/sp08SiS9

idc.py:
    pastebin.com/6eJRtphF

What this script must do is get all the offsets from the game and place them in txt file in the "output" dir.

Let me know if you need any other code.

Comment: Are you running the IDAPython script from within IDA?

Comment: No I actually wasn't. Kinda stupid xDDDD

Comment: That was my guess, I posted that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a python script as an IDAPython script, it must be run from within IDA, either manually or using the basic headless command line arguments IDA supports.